# Calculated Column using Product Custom Attribute in Zend_Db_Expr

Tags: collection, product-collection

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('computed' => new Zend_Db_Expr ('custom_attr * (-1)')));
```

This gives me

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'custom_attr' in 'field list''
```

I'm trying to add a custom column in the collection based from a product attribute.

Note: I just simplified the expression. Tried addExpressionFieldToSelect() but I know it wouldn't work on flat data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

**addExpressionAttributeToSelect()** should be used to add an expression.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect('custom_attr', '( {{existing_attr}} + 1 )', array('existing_attr'=>'existing_attr'));
```

Comment: Please provide the code you used and mark the answer as accepted. It may serve to future readers.